# Bottom border color is using text color

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I want to wrap an `<a>` around a div. When I add that, the border's colour remains the same orange the text is colored.

The orange turns to black when I toggle `color` rule in Chrome's developer tools, however I obviously don't want the viewer to be required to do the same.

Notice that only the Block Fuse project box has this issue, none of the other boxes do because they do not have an `<a>` tag.

I have reproduced this issue in:

- Chrome Version 23.0.1271.95
- Chrome Canary Version 25.0.1342.0

Here is the relavent html:

```html
<a href="projects/blockfuse.html">
<div class="project">
    <div class="projectTitle">Block Fuse</div>
    <div class="projectDescription">Block Fuse is a game about knocking as many blocks onto the floor as possible.
        <div class="projectImage"><img class="projectImage" src="images/BlockFuse.png"></img></div>
    </div>
</div>
</a>
```

Here is the relavant css:

```css
div.projectTitle {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20pt;
    color: #F90;
    padding: 20px 0px 15px 0px;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", Sans-Serif;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
    border-color: black;
    background-color: #444;
}

div.projectDescription {
    height: 310px;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: #EEE;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    background-color: #777;
    padding: 17px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
}
```

[image: Showing the orange bottom border, notice only this project box has this issue since it has an a tag]

Try it live on my website: http://www.rollingkinetics.com/index.html

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Why not? It's perfectly valid HTML5.

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue in that version of Chrome - the bottom border under all headers is black.  Maybe you need to clear your cache? (Preferences > Show Advanced Settings > Clear Browsing Data > "Empty the Cache)?

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue either.

Comment: I just updated my chrome to the version he showed above, and the problem is reproduced.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev How else could I make the entire box a link?

Comment: @ScottS No luck I'm afraid. I am also testing on a local copy where I would assume caching wouldn't take place.

Comment: it should be a new bug, you should call it in: menu - tool - report an issue.

Comment: @xiaoyi Good idea, I will report it now.

Comment: What OS are you using? I've just updated to that version on Windows 8 and cannot replicate the issue. Does the `!important` suffix help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you need to set the color for the `a:visited` selector.  I did not see the issue initially, but i did after I clicked on the link.

Comment: Well spotted. I see the same effect.

Comment: Looks like this is the best workaround for now. Thanks for the eagle-eyed answer.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to place the hyperlink *inside* the div. This makes a better behavior as I experienced.
(in this case the link will be applied for the children of the div and the outer wont get additional a:link color)

Comment: I will do so in the future - however this doesn't fix the issue. Even with `textdecoration: none;`

Answer (score 0):

make text decoration none on hyper link just add this

```
a{
  text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: That doesn't fix it I'm afraid.

Comment: If that had worked, it would mean something very strange was up with Chrome!